# Translatable strings and Drupal primary language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I use a lot of modules and templates, in which I have to `print` a lot of display markups.

My website has primary language FR, but whatever I do, each time I use a **translatable string**, it's always EN that is set for that `t('whatever')`.

I'd like to be able to write all my custome code in French, and then translate strings into english in the interface.

Is it any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately, strings passed to t() should always be in English.